# Как парсить информацию

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Как парсить информацию в html используя HtnlAgilitiPack что бы вывод происходил в TextRichBox

```
 <div class="Text">
        <p>
          1) Я живу в маленьком доме у самого моря. Чтобы увидеть море, нужно
          выйти за калитку и немного пройти по протоптанной в снегу тропинке. Море
          не замёрзло.Снег лежит до самой кромки воды. Когда на море подымается
          волна, то слышен не шум воды, а хрустенье льда и шорох оседающего снега.
          Балтика зимой пустынна и угрюма. По горизонту весь день лежит слоями
          тяжёлая мгла.В ней пропадают очертания низких берегов. Только кое- где в
          этой мгле опускаются над морем белые косматые полосы – там идёт снег.
        </p>
        <p>
          2)Вечером кромешная темнота окружает дом, сосны придвигаются к нему
          вплотную, и, когда выходишь из освещенного дома наружу, тебя охватывает
          ощущение полного одиночества с глазу на глаз с зимой, морем и ночью.
          Море уходит на сотни миль в чёрно- свинцовые дали. На нём не видно ни
          одного огонька. И не слышно ни единого всплеска, словно в расплывчатой
          туманной бездне обрывается земля.
        </p>

        <p>
          3)К западу, в сторону Вентспилса, за слоем мглы есть маленький рыбачий
          посёлок. Обык-новенный рыбачий посёлок с сетями, сохнущими на ветру, с
          низкими домами и низким дымом из труб, с чёрными моторками, вытащенными
          на песок, и доверчивыми собаками с косматой шерстью. В посёлке сотни лет
          живут латышские рыбаки. Поколения сменяют друг друга. Светловолосые
          девушки с застенчивыми глазами и певучим говором становятся
          обветренными, кряжистыми старухами, закутанными в тяжёлые платки. 19)
          Румяные юноши в щегольских кепках превращаются в щетинистых стариков с
          невозмутимыми глазами.
        </p>

        <p>
          4)Но так же, как и сотни лет назад, рыбаки уходят в море за салакой. И
          так же, как и сотни лет назад, не все возвращаются обратно.Особенно
          осенью, когда Балтика свирепеет от штормов и кипит холодной пеной, как
          чертов котел.
        </p>

        <p>
          5)Но что бы ни случилось, сколько бы раз ни пришлось стаскивать шапки,
          когда люди узнают о гибели своих товарищей, всё равно надо и дальше
          делать сво1 дело – опасное и тяжёлое, завещанное дедами и отцами.
          Уступать морю нельзя.
        </p>

        <p>
          6)В море около посёлка лежит большой гранитный валун. На нём еще давно
          рыбаки высекли надпись: « В память всех, кто погиб и погибнет в
          море».Эту надпись видно издалека.
        </p>

        <p>
          7)Когда я узнал об этой надписи, она мне показалась печальной, как все
          эпитафии. Но латышский писатель, рассказавший мне о ней, не согласился с
          этим и сказал: – Наоборот. Это очень мужественная надпись. Она говорит,
          что люди никогда не сдадутся и будут делать своё дело. Я бы поставил эту
          надпись эпиграфом к любой книге о человеческом труде и упорстве. Для
          меня эта надпись звучит примерно так: «В память тех, кто одолевал и
          будет одолевать это море».
        </p>

        <p>
          8)Я согласился с ним и подумал, что этот эпиграф подходил бы и для книги
          о писательском труде.
        </p>

        <p>
          9)Писатели не могут ни на минуту сдаться перед невзгодами и отступить
          перед преградами. Что бы ни случилось, они должны непрерывно делать свой
          дело, завещанное им предшественниками и доверенное современниками.
        </p>

        <p>
          10)Недаром Салтыков – Щедрин говорил, что если хоть на минуту замолкнет
          литература, то это будет равносильно смерти народа.
        </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Что именно у вас вызвало затруднения? Документацию читали, что-то пытались сами сделать?

Comment: Добрый день, я читал документацию и смотрел видеоуроки по данной теме, но все парсят именно сайт , а не Html документ. Я пробовал писать по аналогии, но из за не хватки знаний в данной области решил обратиться к более знающим людям за объяснениям и  примером.

Comment: Так страницу сайта всегда сначала скачивают, чтобы начать её парсить, поэтому непонятно, в чём особая разница, у вас проще ещё всё должно быть.

Comment: `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);` и можно работать с этим `doc`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению проявляется ошибка "Недопустимый URI: Не возможно определить форму URI"